# Unusual Permission for Directory

Tags: linux, fedora, permissions

I am using Fedora as shown below:

```
[root@PANTRY 1000]# os
Linux 6.5.12-200.fc38.x86_64 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Mon Nov 20 22:12:09 UTC 2023 unknown
[root@PANTRY 1000]#
```

I have a sub directory that is showing unusual permissions, called 'doc', see below:

```
[root@PANTRY 1000]# ld
ls: cannot access 'doc': Permission denied
ls: cannot access 'gvfs': Permission denied
drwx------. 4 me me  80 Nov 28 21:13 app
drwx------. 2 me me  60 Nov 28 20:07 at-spi
drwx------. 2 me me  60 Nov 29 06:30 dconf
d?????????? ? ?  ?    ?            ? doc
drwx--x--x. 2 me me  60 Nov 29 00:36 gdm
drwx------. 3 me me  60 Nov 28 20:07 gnome-shell
drwx------. 2 me me  40 Nov 28 20:07 gnupg
d?????????? ? ?  ?    ?            ? gvfs
drwx------. 2 me me  40 Nov 29 08:23 gvfsd
drwx------. 2 me me 100 Nov 28 20:07 keyring
drwx------. 2 me me  80 Nov 28 20:07 pulse
drwxr-xr-x. 7 me me 180 Nov 28 20:44 systemd
[root@PANTRY 1000]#
```

It is located as shown below:

```
[root@PANTRY 1000]# pwd
/run/user/1000
[root@PANTRY 1000]#
```

I have never created this directory intentionally.

I am unable to 'cd' into that directory, even as 'root', see below:

```
[root@PANTRY 1000]# cd /run/user/1000/doc/
bash: cd: /run/user/1000/doc/: Permission denied
[root@PANTRY 1000]#
```

I do notice that 'gvfs' has similar permissions but have seen that before.
Is this an artifact or a real directory and how should I deal with it?

Answer (score 1):

`/run` and `/run/user/<$UID>` mounts are BOTH in-memory filesystems of type `tmpfs`, so you're right that it's not a "real" (read: persistent-storage-backed) directory.

`/run/user/<$UID>/doc` and `/run/user/<$UID>/gvfs` mounts are also in-memory filesystems of type `fuse.portal`. This FUSE module's filesystem has the distinction of being **only readable by the user ID that controls it**. Even `root` (UID 0) cannot read from this mount unless of course `root` uses `su <username>` or `sudo -i -u <username>` to open a shell as that user.

You can check your mounts and their types by running:

```bash
mount |grep /run
```

You can apparently specify `fusermount -o allow_other ...` when mounting to allow non-owners to access FUSE filesystems, but I'm unaware how to mount this directory, or change the options it's currently using. Un-mounting via `fusermount -u /run/user/1000/doc` may cause issues.

### What use is it?

According [to the latest draft of FHS (File Hierarchy Standard)](http://www.linuxbase.org/betaspecs/fhs/fhs.html#runRuntimeVariableData), `/run`:

> This directory contains system information data describing the system since it was booted. Files under this directory must be cleared (removed or truncated as appropriate) at the beginning of the boot process.
>
> The purposes of this directory were once served by /var/run. In general, programs may continue to use /var/run to fulfill the requirements set out for /run for the purposes of backwards compatibility. Programs which have migrated to use /run should cease their usage of /var/run, except as noted in the section on /var/run.
>
> Programs may have a subdirectory of /run; this is encouraged for programs that use more than one run-time file. Users may also have a subdirectory of /run, although care must be taken to appropriately limit access rights to prevent unauthorized use of /run itself and other subdirectories.

(*"Must be cleared during the boot process" eh? Sounds like a perfect use of an in-memory file system!*)

In the case of the `/run/user/<$UID>` directory, is created by [`pam_systemd`](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/pam_systemd.html) or [`elogind`](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Elogind) upon user login and is used by the different user programs that run in the background, like dconf, pulse, gnome-keyring-daemon, etc. that needs a place for their ephemeral storage such as lock files, PID files, sockets, etc. There are as many directories as different users UIDs are logged in the system. These are typically never stored to disk. The rationale being that they contain information about *running* programs and thus have no use after the system shuts down or is rebooted. This also saves an (albeit tiny) amount of wear-and-tear on SSDs.

Apparently `/run/user/<$UID>/gvfs` is an addition by the GNOME desktop environment specifically for services associated with running GNOME desktop.